# To manage custom locations on Google Maps?

Tags: webapp-rec

These are our requirements for the web-app

- To manage custom locations (e.g. stores). It should support standard fields (e.g. names, address, store owner name, phone, ...) and also customized fields
- It should support coordinate (as an built-in field)
- We can quickly click on the store name to view its location on Google Maps

Is there any web-app for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a product I found recently that might do what you want. You can read about it here: http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=99920

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this fit your criteria - **www.areafarming.com**
Its in alpha right now.
I think it can be modified to store what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You may use iFreeTools Creator - an online database app builder over Google App Engine

Meets all three requirements (database with custom fields, coordinate as a built-in field type, click to view on Google Maps) and more (you can search based on nearness to a geo-location).

For a step-by-step guide on how you can do this, refer to the following blog post..

[Building a Store Locator type Google Maps app over GAE, using iFreeTools](http://blogs.ifreetools.com/2010/11/building-store-locator-type-google-maps.html)

// Disclosure : I wrote code for this web-app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mapfaire.com](http://www.mapfaire.com)

<sub>Disclosure: This is an application that I wrote</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Store Locator Plus for WordPress sites. 
http://www.storelocatorplus.com

Note: We are the author of this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Agile Store Locator, having features such as multiple templates, import Excel Sheet, Map Customization, Time Switch to view current Stores, Direction Service, Snazzy Maps supported, Markers and Clusters and many more features.

https://agilestorelocator.com/